# How to render animation or effects using Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, graphics

I want to draw a projectile of a cannon moving and explosive effects (just simple broken bits flying around).  How should I approach this using Core Graphics (on iPhone)?

I am using an NSTimer to call a render method and update the animated projectile or explosive effects and I have no problem drawing each individual pieces (such as filled rec, or line) but I found that drawRect always erases the previous content and only render the new stuff.

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, use setNeedsDisplayInRect instead of setNeedsDisplay and limit to the small area I was drawing into (Thanks Erica).

Answer (score -2):

There's a r[eally good book on this](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone) at the Pragmatic Programmers site.

Comment: I looked at that book at the book store it only has one chapter on iphone? Is coreanimation on iphone and macosx that simmilar?

Comment: This is not so much an animation issue as it is a rendering issue, so that book won't be of much help (case in point, I have that book so I know).